# How to format a DateTimeAxis label in OxyPlot as "hh AM/PM" string ?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

I am trying to format my DateTimeAxis label in the formatted string of hh AM/PM. Does anyone know, how to format DateTimeAxis in hh AM/PM ? Per their documentation they allow these formatting styles.

```
yyyy year “2011”
yy year “11”
MM month “01”
MMM month “Jan”
MMMM month “January”
w week number “4”
ww week number “04”
dd day “26”
hh hour “04”
HH hour “16”
mm minute “37”
ss seconds “23”
yyyy-MM-dd “2011-01-26”
MM/dd/yyyy “01/26/2011”
```

Comment: Yes, it only gives me hrs from 0 to 24 i want to append Am/Pm as well

Comment: Have you tried `"hh tt"`, per the .NET [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)?

Comment: Thanks Ben, that definitely helped. Before I used to get exception. And now , it does work.

Comment: Previously I was trying to use it for TimeSpanAxis, that's why i was getting exception. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tt` from the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) (like Ben already pointed out).

When the `DateTimeAxis` formats a value it passes your formatstlye to `String.Format` ([Source](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/OxyPlot/Axes/DateTimeAxis.cs#L310)) - so any valid format string should work.